# Can't log in to FTP on Debian with vsftpd

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, unix, vsftpd

I'm trying to setup FTP access to my Apache server but I'm receiving a `530 Login Incorrect` error.

I installed the vsftp package via `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`.

I've tried connecting to `ftp://(my ip address)` with a user I've created, `andrew`, who is part of the `ftp` user group. I've also tried connecting with `root`. I'm sure the passwords are correct.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to connect to my `/var/www/` directory to upload files via an FTP client.

This is what my `vsftpd.conf` file looks like without comments:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

And with comments:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=YES
#
# Run standalone with IPv6?
# Like the listen parameter, except vsftpd will listen on an IPv6 socket
# instead of an IPv4 one. This parameter and the listen parameter are mutually
# exclusive.
#listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
chroot_local_user=YES
# chroot_list_enable=YES
# chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

**Edit:** Below is my `/pam.d/vsftpd.conf` config:

```
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required    pam_shells.so
```

I'd imagine this is likely a problem with users, but I really am not sure!

Comment: Probably noy a bunch of help to you... But these days I reccomend almost everyone use SFTP (which is basically built into openssh these days). To assist with plain old ftp... any relevant pam configs would be helpful (/etc/pam.d/vsftpd.conf ?)

Comment: @lVlint67 Thank you for you reply! I've edited my post to include that config you requested. I appreciate SFTP/SCP but I'd like to set up FTP so I can use the auto-install feature on Wordpress. :)

Comment: As long as `andrew` is not in `/etc/ftpusers` it should work. can `andrew` ssh to the server or log in via console? And what's debian's version of `selinux`? `apparmor?` try restarting the service with any such features disabled just make sure they are not getting in the way.
http://man.he.net/man8/pam_listfile

Comment: @lVlint67 Thanks for the quick reply :) ``andrew`` was actually included in ``/etc/ftpusers``. I removed it, restarted vsftpd. Unfortunately, I'm still not able to log into the FTP server. I am able to log into SSH with that user though.

Comment: I mean you can look at: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_shells see if `andrew`'s shell is in `/etc/shells` otherwise i don't know maybe the logs from `/var/log/messages` `/var/log/auth` or `/var/log/secure` or a vsftp specific log will shed light on the issue... Good luck though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been solved!

I was able to fix it by removing `andrew` from the `ftpusers` file and then setting `chroot_local_user=NO` (instead of of `YES`).

I then had to change the owner of the `/var/www/` directory to allow the `andrew` user to write to it: `chown andrew /var/www/`.

Thanks for all the replies :)

Answer (score 0):

edit the `vsftpd.conf` file; uncomment and change the following:

```
# Allow anonymous FTP? (disabled by default)
anonymous_enable=YES
```

Uncomment this to enable any form of the FTP write command.

```
write_enable=YES
```